# What is "OpType" in C/C++ programing

Tags: c++

In the program, there are many `OpType opType` as a input for functions, but there is no definition/declaration for `OpType opType`. Therefore, the program encountered the error:`‘OpType’ has not been declared`.

In addition, there is a switch-case as below, that get `error: was not declared in this scope`, too:

```
switch (opType)
      {
      case OPTYPE_RET_UNCOND:
      case OPTYPE_JMP_INDIRECT_UNCOND:
      case OPTYPE_JMP_INDIRECT_COND:
      case OPTYPE_CALL_INDIRECT_UNCOND:
      case OPTYPE_CALL_INDIRECT_COND:
      case OPTYPE_RET_COND:
    brtype = 2;
    break;
      case OPTYPE_JMP_DIRECT_COND:
      case OPTYPE_CALL_DIRECT_COND:
      case OPTYPE_JMP_DIRECT_UNCOND:
      case OPTYPE_CALL_DIRECT_UNCOND:
    brtype = 0;
    break;
      default:
    exit (1);
      }
    switch (opType)
      {
      case OPTYPE_JMP_DIRECT_COND:
      case OPTYPE_CALL_DIRECT_COND:
      case OPTYPE_JMP_INDIRECT_COND:
      case OPTYPE_CALL_INDIRECT_COND:
      case OPTYPE_RET_COND:
    brtype += 1;
    break;
```

Comment: Looks like `opType` is an `enum` type, nothing standard anyways, ask the author of that code.

Comment: A snippet of a larger peice of larger code that you've taken out, perhaps? `OPTYPE_RET_UNCOND`, `OPTYPE_JMP_INDIRECT_UNCOND`, etc. look like macros or enums of operations (hence `opType`) like "Unconditional return", "Unconditional indirect jump", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as "OpType" neither in C nor in the C++ language. It is a name that can be declared by the program. If such name is declared by the program, then its meaning depends on that declaration. If such name isn't declared, then the name cannot be used.

If you attempt to use an undeclared identifier, you will get errors such as the ones that you quoted. The solution is to either not use the name, or to declare the name in a way that is compatible with how you use the name.